# Pytorch gcn layer forward pass gives different output each time

Tags: graph, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch-geometric

Each time I execute this script I get different values as output. I do get the same output for each node though since its a complete connected graph and the input features are the same for each node. However I would expect to get the same values each time I execute it.

I need to be able to just have the forward pass that produces the same values if the input matrices are the same since I want to use this script to test another GCN Layer that I have coded in a different language for a software project.

As you can see in the code, I made sure to set the weight matrix and bias vector. I also tried to specify the random seed. I saw threads that mention dropouts but I am working with just one layer am I? However it still produces different values each time. What could be the problem?

````
import torch
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

x = torch.tensor([[1.0], [1.0], [1.0]], dtype=torch.float)
edge_index = torch.tensor([[0,0,1,1,2,2], [1,2,0,2,0,1]], dtype=torch.long)

conv_layer = GCNConv(in_channels=1, out_channels=1)

new_weight_values = torch.tensor([[1.0]])
new_bias_values = torch.tensor([[0.0]])

conv_layer.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(new_weight_values)
conv_layer.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(new_bias_values)

output = conv_layer.forward(x, edge_index)

print("Input Features:")
print(x)
print("Output Features:")
print(output)```




As you can see in the code, I made sure to set the weight matrix and bias vector. I also tried to specify the random seed. I saw threads that mention dropouts but I am working with just one layer am I? However it still produces different values each time. What could be the problem?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCNConv has a `.lin` field where the mapping is stored, you are not making this part deterministic.

If you change

```
conv_layer.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(new_weight_values)
```

to

```
conv_layer.lin.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(new_weight_values)
```

it should work as expected.

In fact there is no such thing as `conv_layer.weight`. You are just adding this attribute in your code. If you tried to print it before setting it - you would see an error. (bias is fine though).

Comment: I appreciate the answer a lot since I need it for uni. The output is now deterministic. Though I still get output features I would not expect. It is a GCN layer that is supposed to update once node with the mean of its neighbors and itself. But for the simple graph with 3 nodes named 0,1 and 2 that are connected in a line edges{(0,1),(1,2)} bidirectional and with the input feature values 10 for node 0, 20 for node 1, 30 for node 2 I get as the output feature for node 1 the value 17.0711 which I cant explain at all. I added the code in my question at the bottom.

Comment: if you have a differernt question, you should ask a separate question, rather than expand the scope of the previous one. This way SO can grow as a database of problem-solution pairs

Comment: I appreciate this honest answer too :) In case you can help me with it here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77026456/pytorch-gcn-layer-forward-pass-produces-unexpected-output-features Thank you anyways